# Press an Accessory button in ListView item header

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am using [This](https://github.com/Embarcadero/RADStudio10.4Demos/tree/master/Object%20Pascal/Multi-Device%20Samples/User%20Interface/ListView/VariableHeightItems) custom Listview application. I wanted to Add 2 Buttons in the header of each item. Apparently that is not possible ? The custom Header only gives One `TextButton`, the accessory button is unclickable for some reason

The below event procedure dose not get triggered when I press the Accessory button (in item header). However, it works with `TextButton`

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ItemClickEx(const Sender: TObject;
    ItemIndex: Integer; const LocalClickPos: TPointF;
    const ItemObject: TListItemDrawable);
  begin

       ShowMessage(ItemObject.Name);
  end;
```

Problem is : Trigger a `ShowMessage()` if an Accessory button in the Item header was pressed. Or, How to add 2 TextButtons in the Item Header.

Notes : The Listview item `ItemAppearance` is `Dynamic Appearance` and the Header appearance is `Custom`. Make sure to set the Accessory button visibility to True.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Check Update @jsotola

Answer (score 0):

i recommend using TListBox, try this videos [TListBox Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFnA9tbBrPs&t=172s)